# Добавить исходники в CMakelist

Tags: c++, makefile

мой небольшой проект начал сильно расти и я решил раскидать его файлы по папкам для удобства не складывать же все в add_executable) и с этим у меня возникла проблема. Не понимаю как сделать это правильно.

вот структура проекта и каталоги в нем:

```
root
- src
   - core
      App.h
      App.cpp
      CMakelist.txt
   CMakelist.txt
main.cpp
CMakelist.txt
```

Вот так выглядит мейклист в root:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(edu)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

## add subdirectory with source files
add_subdirectory(src)

add_executable(edu main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  edu
  core)
```

Вот так он выглядит в src:

```
add_subdirectory(core)
```

И вот так он выглядит в core:

```
set(all_src
        App.h
        App.cpp
        cxxopts.hpp
        Helpers.h
        )


add_library(core)
target_sources(core PUBLIC ${all_src})
```

Проблема в том, что теперь файлы, которые я раскидал по папкам, перестали видеть глобальные импорты хедеров и других файлов из других папок. Как починить это?

И вообще как просто раскидать исходного проекта по папкам. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего проекта хватит подобной конфигурации:

```
project/
 -build/
    CMakeLists.txt
 -include/
    *.h
 -src/
   *.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```bsh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(project_name VERSION 1.0)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
file (GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../src/*.cpp 
)

add_executable(project_name ${SRC_FILES})

target_include_directories(project_name PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../include)
```

Comment: есть мнение, что GLOB_RECURSE  , как и другой "глоббинг" плохо использовать. Рекомендуется перечислять файлы вручную. Ну или при изменении кол-ва файлов запускать перегенерацию проекта